# Foreign Key saying "NULL" when it should be an int?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I'm building a question and answer site and I have two tables as of now (questions and answers)  I need the id field of the answer table to be a foreign key in the question table so I can have multiple answers linked to one question.  When I put not null the php code wont work?  Here are my tables:

```
create table answers (
    a_id int not null auto_increment, 
    answer varchar(100) not null, 
    primary key (a_id)
);

create table questions (
    q_id int not null auto_increment,
    question varchar(100) not null,
    a_id int,
    primary key (q_id),
    foreign key (a_id) references answers (a_id)
);
```

I need to have a number in the foreign key section so a user can see all answers to his or her questions.  I've searched online for hours and hours so I've come to stackoverflow.  I hope someone can help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can format source code with the `{}` toolbar button; I've done it for you this time.

Comment: So, the PHP code doesn't work... Don't you think that's the part we need to see? What error does it produce?

Comment: With your current design, a question can have zero or one answers, and an answer does not necessarily need to have a question. If you want a quiz-type app your design is reversed. If you want a 1 question 1 answer app you don't really need two tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wouldn't the table "answers" be the one to have the foreign key referencing questions a_id? Something like this below:

```sql
create table questions (
    q_id int not null auto_increment
    , question varchar(100) not null
    , primary key (q_id)
);

create table answers (
    a_id int not null auto_increment
    , answer varchar(100) not null
    , q_id int not null
    , primary key (a_id)
    , foreign key (q_id) references questions(q_id)
);
```

Perhaps I'm missing something, but that would be my idea.

Comment: Thank you.  I did try this a couple hours ago and think I got the same result but I'll try again.

Comment: If that doesn't work out for you, it's probably the way you're writing/reading the data and I'd need more info to help.

Comment: I copy and pasted your tables into my system and the orders worked fine but for the answers table I got "ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' primary key (a_id)
    , foreign key (q_id) references questions(q_id)
)' at line 5"

Comment: maybe it is something in my php code.  Thanks for the help though man!

Comment: got the table to work but when I ran the code it said this: "Error: INSERT INTO answers (answer) VALUES ('hey dude')
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`questions87`.`answers`, CONSTRAINT `answers_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`q_id`) REFERENCES `questions` (`q_id`))"   It must be my php code issue I guess.

Comment: There was an extra comment in my code! hahaha. It was just before primary key in the answers table. Alright I'll look into this next error and let you know if I can make sense of it.

Comment: Yes you'll need to adapt your php to reference the parent question when inserting into the answers table, so that you satisfy the foreign key constraint.